# Contar cuántas variables estan vacias con PHP

Tags: php

Buenas tardes necesito su ayuda, tengo que hacer una consulta en mi base de datos y para esto tengo que identificar cuantas variables estan vacias, por ejemplo tengo las siguientes variables:

```
$a,$b,$c,$d
```

de estas variables tengo que contar cuántas están vacías, he buscado pero aún no encuentro solucion, espero me puedan ayudar

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar el método [empty()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php)

```
if (empty(variable)) {
    echo 'variable es o bien 0, vacía, o no se encuentra definida en absoluto';
}
```